# C++ get period of an std::chrono::duration

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I was playing arround with std::chrono.
While I do some testing I wonder if I can get the ratio that was used to construct a std::chrono::duration because I want to print it.

Here some code to show what exactly I want to do:

You schould be able to compile this on windows and linux (g++) by adding the `-std=c++11` flag.
This small sample code should measure the time your machine needs to `cout` to max int value.

main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include "stopchrono.hpp"
#include<chrono>
#include<limit>

int main (){
    stopchrono<> main_timer(true);
    stopchrono<unsigned long long int,std::ratio<1,1000000000>,std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> m_timer(true);//<use long long int to store ticks,(1/1000000000)sekond per tick, obtain time_point from std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> 
    stopchrono<unsigned long long int,std::ratio<1,1000000000>> mtimer(true);


    std::cout<<"count to max of int ..."<<std::endl;
    for(int i=0;i<std::numeric_limits<int>::max();i++){}
    std::cout<<"finished."<<std::endl;

    main_timer.stop();
    m_timer.stop();
    mtimer.stop();
    std::cout<<std::endl<<"It took me "<<(main_timer.elapsed()).count()<<" Seconds."<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"            "<<(m_timer.elapsed()).count()<<std::endl;//print amount of elapsed ticks by std::chrono::duration::count()
    std::cout<<"            "<<(mtimer.elapsed()).count()<<std::endl;

    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

stopchrono.hpp

```
#ifndef STOPCHRONO_DEFINED
#define STOPCHRONO_DEFINED

#include<chrono>

template<class rep=double,class period=std::ratio<1>,class clock=std::chrono::steady_clock> //this templates first two parameters determines the duration type that will be returned, the third parameter defines from which clock the duration will be obtained 
class stopchrono { // class for measurement of time programm parts are running
    typename clock::time_point start_point;
    std::chrono::duration<rep,period> elapsed_time;
    bool running;
public:
    stopchrono():
        start_point(clock::now()),
        elapsed_time(elapsed_time.zero()),
        running(false)
    {}
    stopchrono(bool runnit)://construct already started object
    running(runnit),
    elapsed_time(elapsed_time.zero()),
    start_point(clock::now())
    {}

    void start(){//set start_point to current clock::now() if not running
        if(!running){
            start_point=clock::now();
            running=true;
        }
    }
    void stop(){// add current duration to elapsed_time
        if(running){
            elapsed_time+=std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<rep,period>>(clock::now()-start_point);
            running=false;
        }
    }
    void reset(){// set elapsed_time to 0 and running to false
        elapsed_time=elapsed_time.zero();
        running=false;
    }
    std::chrono::duration<rep,period> elapsed(){//return elapsed_time
        if(running){
            return (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<rep,period>>(elapsed_time+(clock::now()-start_point)));
        }else{
            return (elapsed_time);
        }
    }
    bool is_running()const{// determine if the timer is running
        return running;
    }
};
#endif
```

actual sample output

```
count to max of int ...
finished.

It took me 81.6503 Seconds.
            81650329344
            81650331344
```

target sample output

```
count to max of int ...
finished.

It took me 81.6503 Seconds.
            81650329344 (1/1000000000)sekonds 
            81650331344
```

How can I obtain the used period `std::ratio<1,1000000000>` from the returned duration even if I don't know which I have used to create the stopchrono object?
Is that even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `std::chrono::duration` class has a typedef `period` which is what you are looking for. You can access it via `decltype(your_variable)::period`. Something like the following should do

```
auto elapsed = main_timer.elapsed();
cout << elapsed.count() << " " << decltype(elapsed)::period::num << "/"
     << decltype(elapsed)::period::den << endl;
```

See also [this working example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3031e97fbb09b865) which prints the elapsed time and the ratio of seconds.

Comment: @RobertHensing An updated example is [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ff7c26bdaf960d1).

Comment: [Here's one with a fancy stringifier](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14fcf43ebf95670a)  (that I wrote for my own use, and thought it'd be nice to share)